# What is the size of A ∩ B?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

There is a 4 digit PIN.

I know that there are 10000 numbers are available.

Assume A stars with 0 => In this case, 1000 numbers are available. (0000~0999)

Assume B starts with 0 and ends with 0. 100 numbers are available.

Can you tell me they are correct or not? and answer 5 as well.

1. Pr(A) is 0.1 (1000/10000 => A's availabilities/total availabilities)
2. Pr(B) is 0.01 (100/10000 => B's availabilities/total availabilities)
3. Pr(A ∩ B) is the same as Pr(B) so, 0.01
4. Pr(B|A) is 0.1
5. What is the size of A ∩ B is 100? or what should I have to write?

Comment: (1)-(4) are correct, I don't understand what the question is in (5). If it is asking what size of $A \cap B$ is, and your answer is $100$, you are correct.

Comment: First of all, I'm assuming that $A$ and $B$ are *events* that a random number meets a criteria, not the numbers themselves. Do both of these events consider the same number? Or are they chosen independantly?

Comment: @Angelica Maybe Yes.

Comment: @ gt6989b Thank you. I am still not sure about (5). T.T

Comment: Well, what they would like is a clearer statement of the question; "What is the size of $A \cap B$ is $100$?" is a very unclear question because of some mangled grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the random process you are considering is the following:

Randomly select a PIN number $x$ from the state space of all possible PINs $U$. Then $A$ is the event $x$ starts with 0, and $B$ is the event $x$ both starts and ends with 0.

Then we have $\vert U\vert=10000$, $\vert A\vert=1000$, and $\vert B\vert=100$

The answers to (1) and (2) follow from the sizes of the events and state space. $P(A)=\frac{\vert A\vert}{\vert U\vert}=\frac{1000}{10000}=0.1$.

Now for question (3) you note that the probability is the same as (2). This is because you know, on some intuitive level, that $A\cap B$ is just as likely as $B$. What might not be clear is that this is *because of* the answer to (5). See, the formula used for (3) is the same as the one used in (1) and (2).

$$P(B)=\frac{\vert B\vert}{\vert U\vert}=\frac{100}{10000}=0.01$$
$$P(A\cap B)=\frac{\vert A\cap B\vert}{\vert U\vert}=\frac{100}{10000}=0.01$$

Note that contained within this, we have the equality $\vert A\cap B\vert=100$

---

For a more broadly applicable solution, we need to first solve (5) and use the answer in (3). So we need to find the size of the event $A\cup B$.

Note that $B$ is a subset of $A$. This means that every outcome in $B$ is also in $A$. Now $A\cap B$ is the set of outcomes which are in both $A$ and $B$. But if an outcome is in $B$, it's in $A$ also, so $B=A\cap B$. Since the events are equal, it follows that their sizes are equal: $\vert A\cap B\vert=\vert B\vert=100$.